# Data Arrangement Excel and SQL Server

Tags: sql, excel

Hi i need to arrange below data based on column 1 value in an order without sorting like after first 2 rows I need row 12 as this comes in this group. Kindly suggest Excel macro or SQL script.

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7
V(e)    DOS X   Y       Y   Binders, and mixtures thereof, as follows
V(e)(1) DOS X   Y       Y   AMMO (azidomethylmethyloxetane and its polymers) (CAS 90683–29–7)
I   DOS X   Y       Y   Firearms, Close Assault Weapons and Combat Shotguns
I(a)    DOS X   Y       Y   Non-automatic and semi-automatic firearms to caliber .50 inclusive (12.7 mm)
I(b)    DOS X   Y       Y   Fully automatic firearms to .50 caliber inclusive (12.7 mm)
2B001.e DOC AT1,NS2 Y       Y   Machine tools for removing metals, ceramics or "composites",     having all of the following:
2B001.e.1   DOC AT1,NS2 Y       Y   Removing material by means of any of the following: 
2B001   DOC AT1,NP1,NS2 Y       Y   Machine tools and any combination thereof, for removing (or cutting) metals, ceramics or "composites," which, according to the manufacturer's technical specifications, can be equipped with electronic devices for "numerical control", as follows (see List of Items Controlled).
2B001.a DOC AT1,NP1,NS2 Y       Y   Machine tools for turning having all of the following:
I(c)    DOS X   Y       Y   Firearms or other weapons (e.g. insurgency-counterinsurgency, close assault weapons systems) having a special military application regardless of caliber
V(e)(2) DOS X   Y       Y   BAMO-3-3-(bis(azidomethyl)oxetane and its polymers) (CAS 17607–20–4) (see paragraph (g)(1)of this category)
2B001.a.1   DOC AT1,NP1,NS2 Y       Y   Positioning accuracy according to ISO 230/2 (2006) with "all compensations available" equal to or less (better) than 4.5 µm along one or more linear axis
2B001.a.2   DOC AT1,NP1,NS2 Y       Y   Two or more axes which can becoordinated simultaneously for "contouring control"
2B001.e.1.a DOC AT1,NS2 Y       Y   Water or other liquid jets, including those employing abrasive additives
2B001.e.1.b DOC AT1,NS2 Y       Y   Electronic beam
2B001.e.1.c DOC AT1,NS2 Y       Y   "Laser" beam
```

Comment: I cant do sorting because I need values intact in first column and just insert new records  in ordered way. Like if in data value "I" is coming before "B" then its okay but need to enter value "B.1" just after "B"

Answer (score 0):

1. Excel -> Data ribbon -> Text to columns.
2. Select "Next", "Tab" radio and "Finish"
3. Select all data columns
4. Data ribbon -> "Filter"
5. Select header in column 1.
6. "Sort"